# How to find maximum percentage fall in a dataset with Python ? (stock market)

Tags: python, statistics, google-play, stock

I am currently dealing with stock market analysis and trying to find a fast algorithm that enables me to calculate the maximum price drop in a given dataset and, I think it is a good algorithm question to think about. So, the input would be the stock prices of a share for a specific time interval and, the output would be the maximum of all price drops.

Here is a visual example, please look at the picture; (percentages were given by eye decision)

[Stock Price Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH14t.png)

I have roughly represented some price drops and their percentage. Even though the last price drop is the maximum in terms of its value, the one with %60 price drop is the one that I want to find.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the largest drop start on the left (where currently the 30% drop starts) and end where the 60% drop ends? That would be something like a 90% drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

You can do it in linear time by just iterating through the stock values backwards.

You  keep track of the smallest element you have seen so far, as the biggest drop will always go to the smallest value that still lays ahead of it. Then you can calculate the relative drop from every point to the smallest element that is ahead of it and just keep track of the biggest drop you found that way.

Here is an implementation of it in Python. Make sure you understand what I'm doing and why it works, to be sure it fits the problem you had in mind.

```
def getGreatestDrop(stock):
    """Calculates the greatest relative drop of a stock.
    @param stock: 1-D list contianing the values of that stock
    Returns a tuple with the relative drop size, the index of the start and the
    index of the end of that drop.
    """

    min = None # The smallest absolute value seen so far
    minIndex = None  # The index of the smallest absolute value smallest value
    greatestDrop = None # The biggest relative drop seen so far
    greatestDropStart = None # The index of the drop start
    greatestDropEnd = None # The index of the drop end

    # Iterating backwards through the array, starting from the last element
    for index in range(len(stock)-1,-1,-1):
        # Update min
        if min is None or stock[index] < min:
            min = stock[index]
            minIndex = index

        # Calculate relative drop
        drop = 1-min/stock[index]

        # Update greatest drop
        if greatestDrop is None or drop > greatestDrop:
            greatestDrop = drop
            greatestDropStart = index
            greatestDropEnd = minIndex

    # Return values
    return greatestDrop, greatestDropStart, greatestDropEnd
```

---

### Example:

Here is an example program where I use this function on 6 randomly generated stocks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def generateRandomStock(length, volatility=1, trend=0, scale=100, lowest=500):
    """Generat
    @param stock: 1-D list contianing the values of that stock
    Returns a tuple with the relative drop size, the index of the start and the
    index of the end of that drop.
    """
    out = np.ndarray(length)
    value = 0
    for i in range(length):
        value += volatility*(random.random()-0.5) + trend
        out[i] = value
    out *= scale
    out -= out.min()
    out += lowest
    return out

def getGreatestDrop(stock):
    """Calculates the greatest relative drop of a stock.
    @param stock: 1-D list contianing the values of that stock
    Returns a tuple with the relative drop size, the index of the start and the
    index of the end of that drop.
    """

    min = None # The smallest absolute value seen so far
    minIndex = None  # The index of the smallest absolute value smallest value
    greatestDrop = None # The biggest relative drop seen so far
    greatestDropStart = None # The index of the drop start
    greatestDropEnd = None # The index of the drop end

    # Iterating backwards through the array, starting from the last element
    for index in range(len(stock)-1,-1,-1):
        # Update min
        if min is None or stock[index] < min:
            min = stock[index]
            minIndex = index

        # Calculate relative drop
        drop = 1-min/stock[index]

        # Update greatest drop
        if greatestDrop is None or drop > greatestDrop:
            greatestDrop = drop
            greatestDropStart = index
            greatestDropEnd = minIndex

    # Return values
    return greatestDrop, greatestDropStart, greatestDropEnd

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Create subplots
    width = 3
    height = 2
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(width, height)

    # Fix random seed to get the same results every time
    random.seed(42)

    # Draw all plots
    for w in range(width):
        for h in range(height):
            # Generate stocks randomly
            stocks = generateRandomStock(1000)
            axs[w][h].plot(stocks)

            # Calculate greatest drop
            drop, dropStart, dropEnd = getGreatestDrop(stocks)
            axs[w][h].plot([dropStart, dropEnd],[stocks[dropStart],stocks[dropEnd]], color="red")

            # Set title
            axs[w][h].set_title("Greatest Drop is {:.1f}% from {} to {}".format(100*drop, dropStart, dropEnd))

    # Show all results
    plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Example output]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It is understandable and straightforward solution.

Comment: Just realized it was not necessary to go backwards through the list. You could also go forward and keep track of the highest point that you've seen so far and compare that to the current price just as well. I don't know why I thought it had to be backwards...